# Fast way to convert BufferedImage to Jpeg

Tags: java, compression, jpeg, bufferedimage, latency

i'm trying to stream a camera feed over the network,
the main problem that i encountered is the ImageIO latency to encode BufferedImage to jpg

Here is my code:

```
long cameraTimer = 0, cameraTimerFPS = 0, cameraFPS = 0, cameraSize = 0;
while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
    cameraTimer = System.currentTimeMillis();

    BufferedImage imageBuffered = // Get the image

    ImageWriter imageWriter = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg").next();
    ImageWriteParam imageWriterParameter = imageWriter.getDefaultWriteParam();
    imageWriterParameter.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
    imageWriterParameter.setCompressionQuality(cameraCompression / 100F);

    ByteArrayOutputStream imageBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    imageWriter.setOutput(new MemoryCacheImageOutputStream(imageBuffer));

    IIOImage outputImage = new IIOImage(imageBuffered, null, null);
    imageWriter.write(null, outputImage, imageWriterParameter); // ~600ms latency
    imageWriter.dispose();

    // Send the image

    cameraSize += imageBuffer.size();

    cameraTimer = System.currentTimeMillis() - cameraTimer;
    cameraTimer = (1000 / cameraFramerate) - cameraTimer;

    if (cameraTimerFPS - System.currentTimeMillis() < -1000) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Avg Image Size: %s", formatBytes(cameraSize / (cameraFPS + 1))));
        System.out.println(String.format("Frame per second: %s", cameraFPS));
        cameraTimerFPS = System.currentTimeMillis();
        cameraSize = 0;
        cameraFPS = 0;
    }
    cameraFPS++;

    if (cameraTimer > 0) {
        Thread.sleep(cameraTimer);
    }
}
```

So, my question is how can i get rid of the ImageIO api?
i searched on internet and i didn't find any library that can replace the ImageIO.

Comment: replace imageio?? for what? because you do unnecessary things over there? I get around 100-200ms each time for writing the file

Comment: @gpasch we have different hardware it' obvious that if you have powerful PC you get better performance

Comment: You can try to use javax.imageio coupled with the TwelveMonkeys project: https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys . Else, ImageJ has a really quick IO class, but it returns an ImagePlus.

Comment: You should try to move some of the object creations outside of the loop. Also, have you tried IIOImage.writeToSequence or writeInsert ? If it is still too slow, it may be possible to dump the raw data as is to the disk and do the JPEG encoding later.

Comment: What Java version are you using? There has been reports of quite significant performance drop from Oracle JRE 7 to 8 (or any OpenJDK version), due to changes in the Color Management System. However, the time taken to compress the image file is completely meaningless without knowing the dimensions of the image data or the environment you are running on, though. Is writing a BMP for instance much faster? It's also a little unclear what you mean by "latency"... Are you saying that there's no load on the system during those 600ms? Or do you actually mean "processing time"?

Comment: @flanglet Allocating the `ByteArrayOutputStream` and reusing for every iteration may be a good idea. Also, allocating it with a larger size than the default (try to estimate the largest output size and use a value >= that) would help. Other than that, there's no heavy allocation in the loop (from the visible code). Using `writeToSequence()` or `writeInsert()` probably isn't a good idea for JPEG, as it is mostly unsupported in the format.

Comment: @haraldK the java enviroment is: java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode), the code is running on an intel edison (http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/do-it-yourself/edison.html)

Comment: @haraldK switching from java 8 to java 7 (update 90) doesn't give any fps increment

Comment: @Emax Given the limited hardware specs, I am suggesting to write the images as RAW/TIFF/... and do the encoding out of the capture loop.

Comment: @haraldK Instantiating objects inside of a critical speed path is a bad idea regardless of the size of the objects. Eventually it will trigger a GC and this will impact the speed of the critical code.

Comment: @flanglet Technically you may be correct. You might even shave of a ms or two. But compared to the 600ms spent writing the JPEG, I don't think it matters much. There's also lots of instance creation done by the methods called from within the loop, which is out of our control. So the GCs will happen regardless. I'd focus on the big gains first, like using an uncompressed format, as you also suggested.